# Exporting .csv of "selectable options"

Tags: importexport

I have two websites.

On one site I have 4000 products and on the new site I only have 1500.

How can I export the attributes/settings of "selectable options" and update my new site, instead of going into each listing and manually clicking each and every single one of these? 
I have to manually find and click each of the flavor/size for every product. I just want to export from the old site and upload to the new site without exporting entire product listings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBXSv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use the import/export functionality.
Export all of your products, change the fields you need an import them again.
The only thing you need to know are the ids of the options and use them instead of the labels.